# node module error while using intro.js-react

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, intro.js

I was trying to use intro.js- react library for my project onboarding but as sson as i import soething from this package i am getting this bug. i have seen such issue with other packages too. so i think its not related only to this library.
./node_modules/intro.js-react/dist/esm/components/Hints/index.mjs 15:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:19)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |    * @type {Object}
  |    */

> static propTypes = {
> |     enabled: PropTypes.bool,
> |     hints: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({

i tried to delete my node module and reinstall it but it did not work